# RipositoryItemCombobox value not set in devexpress gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I am created windows application in c# in that application i used gridview control of devexpress in first column i used repositoryitemcombobox and bind data in repositorycombobox. combobox has data and when select any data from drop down it display selected value from dropdown but when move to next column previous column value display null

Example :

```
private void gridView1_InitNewRow(object sender, InitNewRowEventArgs e) {
      FoundryBusinessAccess bal = new FoundryBusinessAccess();
      RepositoryItemComboBox comproduct = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
      DataTable dtpro = new DataTable();
      dtpro = bal.SelectProductName();
      List<string> listdata = dtpro.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("prod_name")).ToList();
      foreach (object list in listdata) {
          comproduct.Items.Add(list.ToString());
      }
      gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add(comproduct);
      prod_name.ColumnEdit = comproduct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong event - you should use `CustomRowCellEdit` and/or `CustomRowCellEditForEditing` event instead. Read the following topic from their documentation [Assigning Editors to Individual Cells](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument747).

Comment: i am binding repositoryitemcombobox from database and in that case CustomRowCellEdit event not worked.